# jquery - creating nested json from flat json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Below is the JSON data.

**JSON :**

```
[{
    "Code":"US-AL",
    "Name":"Alabama",
    "Population":4833722
    },
    {
    "Code":"US-AK",
    "Name":"Alaska",
    "Population":735132
    },
    {
    "Code":"US-AZ",
    "Name":"Arizona",
    "Population":6626624
    },
    {
    "Code":"US-AR",
    "Name":"Arkansas",
    "Population":2959373
    },
    {
    "Code":"US-CA",
    "Name":"California",
    "Population":38332521
    },
    {
    "Code":"US-CO",
    "Name":"Colorado",
    "Population":5268367
    },
    {
    "Code":"US-CT",
    "Name":"Connecticut",
    "Population":3596080
}]
```

I wanted to convert that data to this format.

```
[{
    "US-AL": {
        "name" : "Alabama",
        "population" : 4833772
    },
    "US-AK": {
        "name" : "Alaska",
        "population" : 735132
    }
}]
```

I tried with this function and separated the name and population from it.

```
var ParentData = [];
var ChildData = {"name": [], "population": []};

data.forEach(function(val, i) {

    ParentData.push(val.Code);
    ChildData.name.push(val.Name);
    ChildData.population.push(val.Population);

})
```

But I'm not that expert in this. Just a learner and I don't know how to push to the parent data which gets aligned to it respectively.

Any help will be very much helpful for me to achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var newData = {};
data.forEach(function(val) {
    newData[val.Code] = {name: val.Name, population: val.Population};
});
```

Keep in mind that forEach isn't natively supported by IE8-, although it can be polyfilled. This works in every browser:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
    newData[data[i].Code] = {name: data[i].Name, population: data[i].Population};
```

Or, since you added the "jquery" tag, you can also use:

```
$.each(data, function() {
    newData[this.Code] = {name: this.Name, population: this.Population};
});
```

Comment: How can I push it to a array?

Comment: @UnknownUser What do you mean? What we've created - and looks like you wanted - is an *object literal*, not an array. You can either wrap it into an array (getting something like the one in your question), or push it to an existing array, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Try with native `map` of javascript

```
var newData = data.map(function (obj) {
    var newObj = {};
    newObj[obj.Code] = {};
    newObj[obj.Code].name = obj.Name;
    newObj[obj.Code].population = obj.Population;
    return newObj;
});

console.log(newData)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[{
   "US-AL":{
     "name":"Alabama",
     "population":4833722
   }
 },
 {
   "US-AK":{
     "name":"Alaska",
     "population":735132
   }
 },
 {
   "US-AZ":{
     "name":"Arizona",
     "population":6626624
   }
 },
 {
   "US-AR":{
     "name":"Arkansas",
     "population":2959373
   }
 },
 {
   "US-CA":{
     "name":"California",
     "population":38332521
   }
 },
 {
   "US-CO":{
     "name":"Colorado",
     "population":5268367
   }
 },
 {
   "US-CT":{
     "name":"Connecticut",
     "population":3596080
   }
 }
]
```

And the code:

```
var newDatas = datas.map(function(item) {
    var obj = {};
    obj[item.Code] = { name: item.Name, population: item.Population };
    return obj;
});
```

`datas` is the array containing your original source.