# Converting CSV to JSON - jQuery

Tags: jquery, json, csv, d3.js

I'm trying to convert a data from csv to json, but I wanted the data to follow some hierarchy.

This is my CSV

```
link,model,role,access
link1,model1,role1,true
link1,model1,role2,true
link1,model1,role3,true
link1,model1,role4,true
link1,model2,role1,false
link1,model2,role2,false
link1,model2,role3,false
link1,model2,role4,false
link2,model1,role1,false
link2,model1,role2,true
link2,model1,role3,false
link2,model1,role4,true
link2,model2,role1,false
link2,model2,role2,true
link2,model2,role3,false
link2,model2,role4,true
```

Expected result

```
"link1": {
    "model1": {
        "role1": true,
        "role2": true,
        "role3": true,
        "role4": true,
    },
    "model2": {
        "role1": false,
        "role2": false,
        "role3": false,
        "role4": false,
    }
},
"link2": {
    "model1": {
        "role1": false,
        "role2": true,
        "role3": false,
        "role4": true,
    },
    "model2": {
        "role1": false,
        "role2": true,
        "role3": false,
        "role4": true,
    }
}
```

I tried to do it from this [jquery - creating nested json from flat json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24989966/jquery-creating-nested-json-from-flat-json), but the thing is it has only 1 level, but in my case it's two levels.

I thought of doing it something like this,

```
data.forEach(function(val) {
        newData[val.link] = {val.model :  {val.role: val.access}};
    });
```

But couldn't really get it to work. I'm pretty new to the data part, any help or suggestion will be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is actually simple enough to parse the CSV format in this particular case. See the snippet below.

I have split the main CSV string by `\n` to get the lines. Now skipping the first line (which is the header), you just need to get value of every column and push it into the result `obj`.

```js
var str = `link,model,role,access
link1,model1,role1,true
link1,model1,role2,true
link1,model1,role3,true
link1,model1,role4,true
link1,model2,role1,false
link1,model2,role2,false
link1,model2,role3,false
link1,model2,role4,false
link2,model1,role1,false
link2,model1,role2,true
link2,model1,role3,false
link2,model1,role4,true
link2,model2,role1,false
link2,model2,role2,true
link2,model2,role3,false
link2,model2,role4,true`;

var lines = str.split('\n');
var obj = {};
// Ignore the first line as it contains only the header info.
for(var i = 1; i < lines.length; i++) {
  var lineItems = lines[i].split(',');
  var link = lineItems[0];
  var model = lineItems[1];
  var role = lineItems[2];
  var roleValue = lineItems[3];
  
  if(obj[link] == undefined) {
    obj[link] = {};
  }
   
  if(obj[link][model] == undefined) {
    obj[link][model] = {};
  }
  
  obj[link][model][role] = roleValue;
}

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: Wow man!!! This is so cool. Thanks a lot, I have another doubt, can you pls help me out?

Comment: Yeah, sure. Anything related to this question?

Comment: Yes it is related to this question, I just put a same CSV over there. But I have a lot of lines, I found a way to convert them to JSON using d3.js. With the converted JSON will this code work?

Comment: Which question? I don't see any links in your code!

Comment: The same question for which you've already answered me. After I convert the CSV to JSON using d3.js, I have a JSON output stored in a variable. Will I be able to pass the JSON to your code which you answered me now?

Comment: I'm not sure about the d3 part, as I haven't used it anywhere. Do you have a fiddle somewhere that makes use of it? I can probably judge from that. Or, you could post a separate question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154845/discussion-between-unknown-user-and-nisarg-shah).

Answer (score 0):

Since its tagged in d3, a d3 way would be something like this:

- Using d3.CSV
- Then rolling up values using d3.nest

```js
    d3.csv("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/cyrilcherian/649d692647ddc70afda93be607427221/raw/bbb95b10d1aca62b17f75534039fb7e8a7c911ba/some.csv", function(data) {;
      var nested_data = d3.nest()
        .key(function(d) {
          return d.link;
        })
        .key(function(d) {
          return d.model;
        })
        .rollup(function(leaves) {
          return {
            role1: leaves.find(d => d.role == "role1").access,
            role2: leaves.find(d => d.role == "role2").access,
            role3: leaves.find(d => d.role == "role3").access,
            role4: leaves.find(d => d.role == "role4").access
          };
        })
        .entries(data);
      console.log(nested_data)
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.10.2/d3.js"></script>
```

It returns data in a key/values fashion which need to be mapped as per your JSON format.

Not complete but I thought of sharing.

Comment: Here is a plunk i was playing around in case you need it http://plnkr.co/edit/jemffA2RHPFjJdSHjz3g?p=preview

Comment: Hey, thank you for your response. But the nested_data isn't the format what I'm looking for. I don't want the "key" or "values" to be present there instead I only want the name of it. Only "models" and "link".

Comment: yep exactly, the one you accepted as answer is a better way out.
using d3.nesting i cant make it as per the structure you expecting.