# Converting an array of object - JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, d3.js

I have an array on objects like this,

```
[
  {
    "link": "link1",
    "model": "model1",
    "role": "role1",
    "access": "true"
  },
  {
    "link": "link1",
    "model": "model1",
    "role": "role2",
    "access": "true"
  },
  {
    "link": "link1",
    "model": "model1",
    "role": "role3",
    "access": "true"
  },
  {
    "link": "link1",
    "model": "model1",
    "role": "role4",
    "access": "true"
  },
  {
    "link": "link1",
    "model": "model2",
    "role": "role1",
    "access": "false"
  },
  {
    "link": "link1",
    "model": "model2",
    "role": "role2",
    "access": "false"
  },
  {
    "link": "link1",
    "model": "model2",
    "role": "role3",
    "access": "false"
  },
  {
    "link": "link1",
    "model": "model2",
    "role": "role4",
    "access": "false"
  },
  {
    "link": "link2",
    "model": "model1",
    "role": "role1",
    "access": "false"
  },
  {
    "link": "link2",
    "model": "model1",
    "role": "role2",
    "access": "true"
  },
  {
    "link": "link2",
    "model": "model1",
    "role": "role3",
    "access": "false"
  },
  {
    "link": "link2",
    "model": "model1",
    "role": "role4",
    "access": "true"
  },
  {
    "link": "link2",
    "model": "model2",
    "role": "role1",
    "access": "false"
  },
  {
    "link": "link2",
    "model": "model2",
    "role": "role2",
    "access": "true"
  },
  {
    "link": "link2",
    "model": "model2",
    "role": "role3",
    "access": "false"
  },
  {
    "link": "link2",
    "model": "model2",
    "role": "role4",
    "access": "true"
  }
]
```

With respect to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46313712/converting-csv-to-json-jquery/46315097?noredirect=1#comment79593878_46315097), the input was a CSV sample with very less number of rows. In real I have a large CSV file and I found a way to import it and convert to JSON using d3.js, but the problem is I'm unable to convert it to the desired format. I tried using the data.forEach and the output was really weird and I couldn't understand why I get `model2` alone in both the links.

**Code:**

```
d3.csv('data.csv', function(data) {

            var newData = {};

            data.forEach(function(e, i) {
                newData[e.link] = {};
                newData[e.link][e.model] = {};
            })

            d3.select('main').append('pre')
                .text(JSON.stringify(newData, null, '  '));
        });
```

**Output:**

```
{
  "link1": {
    "model2": {}
  },
  "link2": {
    "model2": {}
  }
}
```

---

**Desired Output:**

```
"link1": {
    "model1": {
        "role1": true,
        "role2": true,
        "role3": true,
        "role4": true,
    },
    "model2": {
        "role1": false,
        "role2": false,
        "role3": false,
        "role4": false,
    }
},
"link2": {
    "model1": {
        "role1": false,
        "role2": true,
        "role3": false,
        "role4": true,
    },
    "model2": {
        "role1": false,
        "role2": true,
        "role3": false,
        "role4": true,
    }
}
```

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which is the question?

Comment: This is the question, I wanted to convert the JSON in the top, like the one in the bottom.

Comment: Always this will have 4 roles? role1, role2, role3, role4 ? or is that dynamic?

Comment: No, it is not same always. Some will have 2 and some with 3 and 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your forEach, you're not assigning the role and access pair on each iteration, and you're always emptying each section.

Change your forEach with this...

```
data.forEach(function(e, i) {

    // Check if this "link" already exists exists, if not, create it.
    if (!newData[e.link])
        newData[e.link] = {};

    // Check if this "model" already exists inside of this "link", if not, create it.
    if (!newData[e.link][e.model])
        newData[e.link][e.model] = {};

    newData[e.link][e.model][e.role] = e.access;
});
```

I hope it helps